# Logarithmic iterative algorithm for calculating $x^n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

> Write a logarithmic iterative algorithm for calculating $x^n$ using successive multiplication, where $n$ is a perfect power of $3$.

```
public static int power(int x, int n)
{
    int total = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) // i can be declared here directly
    {   
        total = (x * total);
    }
    return total; // total remains 1 if n = 0   
}
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

This is correct,
but it does not satisfy
the requirements.

You are asked to
write a
"logarithmic iterative algorithm".
This means that
the number of operations
is of order
$\log(n)$.
Your routine takes
$\Omega(n)$
operations.

A hint:
Since
you are given that
$n = 3^m$
for some $m$,
use
$3(3^{m-1})
=3^m
$
and look at
$x^3$.